# C2DM and PHP Server

Tags: php, android, android-c2dm

I'm trying to write the server side of my android app that uses C2DM. I'm going to write it in php. I basically am just doing tests right now. I copied the chrome to phone example for the actual android app and modified it to my liking. Right now my biggest question is the registration.

Let me get everything straightened out.

When registering the device for the first time, the app talks directly to my server. The server grabs the deviceid and responds back with a 200. Right?

So, on the php side of things, I grab the device id like $deviceid = $_POST['deviceId'] Right?
add it to my database. then respond back to the app.. How exactly do I send a particular response back? I assume in the header? I'm unsure how to do that.

Please confirm or deny that I'm on the right track and clear up any confusion.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't respond back to the app. You must register your server with google's servers to get a server authentication token. You then use that server token and the device token in a post request to google's C2DM service to have google's servers send a push notification to the phone. Your app and your server never directly communicate when a push notification is sent in C2DM, it is all done through google, yet you need to implement a mechanism for your server to know the device id of the device it wants to send a message to.

This is a pretty detailed guide, though the server code is in Java: 
*[www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html)*

Comment: I understand while sending a push notification... but I mean before that takes place... When my app says "Hey, I would like to receive notifications later. here is my device id" how do I handle that?

Comment: Ok I am assuming you have gotten a device ID on your app. Now what? Its up to you. You must implement a way for your server to get a device id. Somehow, the app needs to tell your server what the device id and whatever other information it needs (for example, what account that device id is tied to). This is all open ended and must be handled by you. You need to implement both the app and server endpoints for passing the device id. This is often done with a post request. Again, the link I put up is a good example.

Comment: Ok, I finally got it working! Just took a ton of research and persistence!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have really gotten the IDs before sending to the server. If you are using an emulator for testing, you could do an `echo` over at the `php` script so the message will appear in your `logcat`.

Google refreshes expired registration IDs so your application should be able to pick up new notifications/ids from google and handle the message by sending to the database.